# ANDROID NAVIGATOR GEOLOCATION

Tags: android, cordova, knockout.js, cordova-plugins

This code is working as it should be on IOS device but is not working on android devince when GPS is closed, it does not break into succeess or fail functions, it does not seems on map.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(controller.geoLocationSuccess, controller.onFailGeoLocation, { enableHighAccuracy: true });

    geoLocationSuccess: function (geoPosition) {
        alert('success');
        controller.setCoords(geoPosition);
        map.addMarker({
            iconSrc: "images/urhere32.png",
            location: [latitude, longitude],
            tooltip: {
                text: title,
                isShown: true
            }
        });
    }

    onFailGeoLocation: function (response, notifytype, code) {
        if (response.code == 1) {
            ui.alert("Şu anda bulunduğunuz noktaya göre çalıştırmak için, ayarlardan bu uygulamaya Lokasyon Servis kullanımına izin veriniz");
            controller.setCoords(GeoCoords);
            map.addMarker({
                iconSrc: "images/urhere32.png",
                location: [latitude, longitude],
                tooltip: {
                    text: title,
                    isShown: true
                }
            });
        }
    }

 setCoords: function (geoPosition) {
        if (viewModel.accountInformations.LATITUDE != 0 && viewModel.accountInformations.LONGITUDE != 0) {
            latitude = viewModel.accountInformations.LATITUDE;
            longitude = viewModel.accountInformations.LONGITUDE;
            title = viewModel.accountInformations.MUST_AD;
        }
        else {
            latitude = geoPosition.coords.latitude;
            longitude = geoPosition.coords.longitude;
            title = "Buradasınız";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in this way, If Geolocation service is turned off the onError callback is invoked after timeout interval (if specified). If timeout parameter is not specified then no callback is called.